# Drupal: How to make a view take argument from session?

Tags: php, drupal

I have a drupal site in which I need to set a value in the session from one page and there is another page (constructed using views) I need the displayed data to be filtered according to the value that previously set into the session.

How could I achieve that? (Just take in mind that I am new to drupal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use filters (not arguments, it is something different), you could use [Views PHP Filter](http://drupal.org/project/viewsphpfilter) module.
Simply add filter of type `PHP code` and return (possibly processed) `$_SESSION['variable']`.

Note that you must run drupal 6, not 7.